# Wordpress: How to display multiple images from each post on the list page

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress question.
Each post has multiple thumbnails, company logo and description. See the mockup: http://d.pr/i/19rBb

And on the homepage, I would like to display all the thumbnails minus the company logo. See the mockup: http://d.pr/i/zyRe

What's the best way to accomplish it? I would like to understand the concept more than the code.
Thanks!

Comment: First off your question is really vague. Second Stack Overflow is more of a question and coding website. I am sure someone here could help you out but you may better luck at: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Probably lots of ways. If you can give the logo thumbnails a different class or tag or otherwise give them an attribute that's distinct, then you can use CSS to display:none them on your home page only.  You do that by adding code that basically says "if this page is the frontpage" img.logo_image {display:none;} "end if"

I there is a div around the images you want to hide the dive might be there but have no image in it. You'd then use jQuery to select the parent div of the image and display:none that div.